# Replace string with multiple different options

Tags: c#, string

Hi there wonderful people of stackOverFlow.

I am currently in a position where im totaly stuck. What i want to be able to do is take out a word from a text and replace it with a synonym. I thought about it for a while and figured out how to do it if i ONLY have one possible synonym with this code.

```
        string pathToDesk = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToDesk + "/Text.txt");
        string replacementsText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToDesk + "/Replacements.txt");
        string wordsToReplace = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathToDesk + "/WordsToReplace.txt");

        string[] words = text.Split(' ');
        string[] reWords = wordsToReplace.Split(' ');
        string[] replacements = replacementsText.Split(' ');

        for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {//for each word 
            for(int j = 0; j < replacements.Length; j++) {//compare with the possible synonyms
                if (words[i].Equals(reWords[j], StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {
                    words[i] = replacements[j];
                }
            }
        }

        string newText = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
            newText += words[i] + " ";
        }

        txfInput.Text = newText;
```

But lets say that we were to get the word hi. Then i want to be able to replace that with {"Hello","Yo","Hola"}; (For example)

Then my code will not be good for anything since they will not have the same position in the arrays.

Is there any smart solution to this I would really like to know.

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`, use the words as key and the list of synonims as value. If your problem is to save/load this data then you can just use an XML serializer, in this way you can even manually create the file.

Comment: that partly works,  any of the synonyms needs to have a key to the rest of the synonyms

Comment: Im really new to the c# language. Just started a few days ago comming in from java. Do you have a working example of how these lists are used?

Answer (score 1):

you need to store your synonyms differently

in your file you need something like

```
hello yo hola hi
awesome fantastic great
```

then for each line, split the words, put them in an array array of arrays

Now use that to find replacement words

This won't be super optimized, but you can easily index each word to a group of synonyms as well.

something like

```
public class SynonymReplacer
    {
        private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _synonyms;

        public void Load(string s)
        {
            _synonyms = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
            var lines = s.Split(new[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var words = line.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
                words.ForEach(word => _synonyms.Add(word, words));
            }
        }

        public string Replace(string word)
        {
            if (_synonyms.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                return _synonyms[word].OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid())
                                      .FirstOrDefault(w => w != word) ?? word;
            }
            return word;
        }
    }
```

The OrderBy gets you a random synonym...

then

```
        var s = new SynonymReplacer();
        s.Load("hi hello yo hola\r\nawesome fantastic great\r\n");
        Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("hi"));
        Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("ok"));
        Console.WriteLine(s.Replace("awesome"));

        var words = new string[] {"hi", "you", "look", "awesome"};
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", words.Select(s.Replace)));
```

and you get :-

```
hello
ok
fantastic
hello you look fantastic
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first task will be to build a list of words and synonyms. A Dictionary will be perfect for this. The text file containing this list might look like this:

```
word1|synonym11,synonym12,synonym13
word2|synonym21,synonym22,synonym23
word3|synonym31,synonym32,synonym33
```

Then you can construct the dictionary like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, string[]> GetSynonymSet(string synonymSetTextFileFullPath)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (var file = new StreamReader(synonymSetTextFileFullPath))
    {
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var split = line.Split('|');
            if (!dict.ContainsKey(split[0]))
            {
                dict.Add(split[0], split[1].Split(','));
            }
        }
    }
    return dict;
}
```

The eventual code will look like this

```
public string ReplaceWordsInText(Dictionary<string, string[]> synonymSet, string text)
{
    var newText = new StringBuilder();
    string[] words = text.Split(' ');
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) //for each word 
    {
        string[] synonyms;
        if (synonymSet.TryGetValue(words[i], out synonyms)
        {
            // The exact synonym you wish to use is up to you.
            // I will just use the first one
            words[i] = synonyms[0];
        }

        newText.AppendFormat("{0} ", words[i]);
    }

    return newText.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you alot. May i just ask you what the counter++ is for? i cant seem to find where that is used in the program or where the variable is at.

Comment: @AlbinWärme I've edited the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.